# Re-reading your .bash_profile

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

When you make a change to your .bash_profile it will be read the next time you open a terminal.  But what if you have a terminal open already. Is there anyway to do a re-read?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `source`

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

From the bash manual:

> ```
>     .  filename [arguments]
>    source filename [arguments]
>           Read and execute commands from filename in the current shell environment and return the exit
>           status  of  the  last command executed from filename.  If filename does not contain a slash,
>           file names in PATH are used to find the directory containing filename.   The  file  searched
>           for  in  PATH need not be executable.  When bash is not in posix mode, the current directory
>           is searched if no file is found in PATH.  If the sourcepath option to the shopt builtin com-
>           mand  is  turned  off, the PATH is not searched.  If any arguments are supplied, they become
>           the positional parameters when filename is executed.  Otherwise  the  positional  parameters
>           are unchanged.  The return status is the status of the last command exited within the script
>           (0 if no commands are executed), and false if filename is not found or cannot be read.
> ```

Comment: Or use the _dot_ version of _source_: `. ~/.bash_profile`